# how to put an image in a svg with a higher z-index

Tags: html, svg, z-index

I have a **svg** and I want to put an image inside of it.

The **svg** looks like a wave.

The image should be in front of the wave (visible) but the problem is it is now hiding behind the wave.

I tried already with a higher `z-index` but without result.

How can I make the image visible in front of the wave?

```
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<symbol id="wave">    
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
    <g>
        <!--<path d="M100,30 Q70,40 50,30 T0,30 v20 h100Z" -->
    <path d="M100,30 Q70,60 50,30 T0,30 v20 h100Z" 
          style="stroke-linejoin:round; stroke:#f6f6f6" stroke-width="0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</symbol>
</svg>      


<div class="svg-header-wave">                       
<svg class="header-wave" style="width: 100%; height: 150px" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <image xlink:href="http://develop.webprofis.nl/wisselslag/img/logo.png" x="0" y="-30" width="300px" height="150px" style="z-index: 9999"/>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
            <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#009de1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#102b72"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

   <use xlink:href="#wave"/>

</svg>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle you can see what happens:
https://jsfiddle.net/jotect8j/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the image tag after the wave.

SVG elements are by default layed over top of one another in the order of their inclusion.

So first element is at the bottom, while last is on top.

```
<svg class="header-wave" style="width: 100%; height: 150px" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
            <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#009de1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#102b72"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#wave"/>

    <image xlink:href="http://develop.webprofis.nl/wisselslag/img/logo.png" x="0" y="-30" width="300px" height="150px" style="z-index: 9999"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gwat00Lr/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<symbol id="wave">    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
        <g>
            <!--<path d="M100,30 Q70,40 50,30 T0,30 v20 h100Z" -->
        <path d="M100,30 Q70,60 50,30 T0,30 v20 h100Z" 
              style="stroke-linejoin:round; stroke:#f6f6f6" stroke-width="0"/>
        </g>
    <image xlink:href="http://develop.webprofis.nl/wisselslag/img/logo.png" x="0" y="-30" width="300px" height="150px" style="z-index: 9999"/>
    </svg>
</symbol>
</svg>      


<div class="svg-header-wave">                       
    <svg class="header-wave" style="width: 100%; height: 150px" fill="url(#gradient)">

        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
                <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#009de1"/>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#102b72"/>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>

       <use xlink:href="#wave"/>

    </svg>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle with working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jotect8j/11/)